# Start playing audio when app is force killed

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have seen many links that the app will play audio when the app is in background. Using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` it is possible.

My question is, lets say the app is killed. but I want to play audio at a particular set time.Even though the app is not in background but force killed. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean, like with a cron job?

Comment: If the app is not running at all, for whatever reason, what can it possibly mean to suggest that "I want to play audio". I who??? There is no app at this time. So who is I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app cannot play sound, or do anything for that matter, if it isn't running. You cannot launch the app if it isn't running, because of the bootstrap problem: "you" *are* the app, and *ex hypothesi*, you are not running and therefore (wait for it) cannot do anything.

The best you can do is attempt to induce the *user* to launch the app for you. For example, you could ask the system to present to the user a notification on your behalf at the set time. The system *is* running (unless the user has turned off the device), so this stands a good chance of working. The user can respond to the notification by launching your app; it isn't certain that the user will do this, but it's a reasonable hope.

Comment: Like Azan feature. Lets say in my location, the prayer starts at 4 am, my phone should start playing the prayer at that time...How can i do this?

Comment: You're just asking me to repeat myself. Read what I said in my answer: arrange for a local notification. But my answer also explains that there are limits to what this can accomplish directly.